# Listar Array segun dato de function javascript

Tags: javascript, html

me ocupa la siguiente function de javascript

```
function videos(a){

  var videos = [{
          nombre: "Video 1",
          ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
          archivo: "presentacion.mp4",
          seccion: 1
      },{
          nombre: "Video 2",
          ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
          archivo: "origenes.mp4",
          seccion: 2
          }

    ];

resultado = "<h1>Prueba de Lista de Videos</h1>";
resultado += "<ul>";
      for (key in videos) {
          var nombre = videos[key];
          var ruta = videos[key];
          var archivo = videos[key];
          var seccion = videos[key];
          var listaNombre = nombre.nombre;
          var listaRuta = ruta.ruta;
          var listaArchivo = archivo.archivo;
          var listaSeccion = seccion.seccion;
          var listaA = listaNombre.toUpperCase();
          var listaB = "<a title='Visitar " + listaNombre + "' class='clase6' href='" + listaRuta + listaArchivo + "' target = '_blank'>" + listaRuta + "</a>";
          // Genera el contenido que va a html contenido
          resultado += "<li>" + listaA + "<br>" + listaB + "<br>" + listaArchivo + "<br><br></li>";
        }
resultado += "</ul>";

  document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = resultado;

}
```

Asi como esta funciona mostrando los 2 videos del ejemplo pero lo que deseo hacer es que si es llamada la `function videos(1)` entonces se cargue solo el `video 1` y si llamo `function videos(2)` se muestre el `video 2` es decir que en numero de la function videos(a) a sea la seccion.

Comment: ¿Cómo se va a llamar a esta función?, ¿Con un botón? Saludos

Comment: Saludos la idea es llamarla de la siguiente manera desde un boton `onclick='videos(1);'` o `onclick='videos(2);'`

Comment: Saludos si la idea de que este dentro de un Array es porque es mas ordenado tener tantos archivos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por favor prueba la siguiente solución, estoy asumiendo que la estructura de tu conjunto de datos es similar a lo que propongo:

```
function videos(a){

        let videos = [{
            nombre: "Video 1",
            ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
            archivo: "presentacion.mp4",
            seccion: 1
        },
        {
            nombre: "Video 2",
            ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
            archivo: "origenes.mp4",
            seccion: 2
        },
        {
            nombre: "Video 2 -1",
            ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
            archivo: "origenes.mp4",
            seccion: 2
        },
        {
            nombre: "Video 2 -2 ",
            ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
            archivo: "origenes.mp4",
            seccion: 2
        }
    ];

    let selectedVideo = videos.filter((item) => (
        item.seccion === a
    ));
    
    let resultado = "<h1>Prueba de Lista de Videos</h1>";
    let nodoDOM = selectedVideo.map((video) => {
        resultado += "<ul>";
        let nombre = video.nombre;
        let ruta = video.ruta;
        let archivo = video.archivo;
        let seccion = video.seccion;
        let listaA = nombre.toUpperCase();
        let listaB = "<a title='Visitar " + nombre + "' class='clase6' href='" + ruta + archivo + "' target = '_blank'>" + ruta + "</a>";
        // Genera el contenido que va a html contenido
        resultado += "<li>" + listaA + "<br>" + listaB + "<br>" + archivo + "<br><br></li>";
        resultado += "</ul>";

        return resultado;
    });

    nodoDOM.map((item) => (document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = item));
    //document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = nodoDOM;  
  }
```

Si funciona, te sugiero un **refactor** en la forma en que pintas los *elementos DOM*, *innerHTML* no es recomendado, necesitas implementar **createElement** e  **insertAdjacentElement** para pintar esos elementos.

Por favor actualiza la respuesta que vayas a elegir.

Comment: Lo implemente de manera perfecta, y si me pondré en ello, no había refactorizado porque este es un aplicativo que funciona offline pero tomare su sugerencia y mejorare mi forma de codificar..! Gracias

Comment: Claro, le sugiero usar ReactJS, es mas práctico trabajar con virtual DOM que con DOM, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haría sería recorrer cada objeto del `array` de vídeos y cuando el atributo **seccion** del objeto sea el que le pasamos como parámetro de entrada a la función, almacenar dicho objeto en una variable. De esa manera ya podemos acceder directamente a los atributos del objeto correcto y pintar la cadena que necesitas devolver en la variable `resultado`.

```js
console.log(videos(2));

function videos(a) {
    let videos = [{
          nombre: "Video 1",
          ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
          archivo: "presentacion.mp4",
          seccion: 1
      },
      {
          nombre: "Video 2",
          ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
          archivo: "origenes.mp4",
          seccion: 2
      },
      {
          nombre: "Video 3",
          ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
          archivo: "origenes.mp4",
          seccion: 2
      }
    ];
   
   let resultado = '';
   
  videos.forEach(function(video) {
    if (video.seccion === a) {
      resultado += "<h1>Prueba de Lista de Videos</h1>";
      resultado += "<ul>";
      let nombre = video.nombre;
      let ruta = video.ruta;
      let archivo = video.archivo;
      let seccion = video.seccion;
      let listaA = nombre.toUpperCase();
      let listaB = "<a title='Visitar " + nombre + "' class='clase6' href='" + ruta + archivo + "' target = '_blank'>" + ruta + "</a>";
      // Genera el contenido que va a html contenido
      resultado += "<li>" + listaA + "<br>" + listaB + "<br>" + archivo + "<br><br></li>";
      resultado += "</ul>";
    }
  });
    

    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: He probado tu solucion y si tengo un solo video en la seccion no hay problema pero  pero si tengo ejemplo 4 videos en la seccion 2 solo muestra el ultimo archivo

Comment: Esta respuesta cumple con lo que mencionas si insertas el html del video dentro del if donde compara la seccion. Como esta aparte solo te deja el ultimo resultado.

Comment: En mi cabeza pensé que solamente podía pintarse un solo vídeo. Actualicé la respuesta para incluir en el bucle `forEach` la asignación de valor de `resultado` para que de esa manera se vaya añadiendo a la variable acumulativa todos los vídeos que cumplan con el patrón de selección.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el array ordenado la posicion del array es el numero que le envías menos 1, y no es necesario declararlo cada vez que hagas click, en este ejemplo lo puse afuera de la función.

```js
var arrvideos = [{
 nombre: "Video 1",
 ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
 archivo: "presentacion.mp4",
 seccion: 1
 },{
 nombre: "Video 2",
 ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
 archivo: "origenes.mp4",
 seccion: 2
 }

 ];

function videos(a){
resultado = "<h1>Prueba de Lista de Videos</h1>";
resultado += "<ul>";

 var xvideo = arrvideos[a-1];
 var listaNombre = xvideo.nombre;
 var listaRuta = xvideo.ruta;
 var listaArchivo = xvideo.archivo;
 var listaSeccion = xvideo.seccion;
 var listaA = listaNombre.toUpperCase();
 var listaB = "<a title='Visitar " + listaNombre + "' class='clase6' href='" + listaRuta + listaArchivo + "' target = '_blank'>" + listaRuta + "</a>";
 // Genera el contenido que va a html contenido
 resultado += "<li>" + listaA + "<br>" + listaB + "<br>" + listaArchivo + "<br><br></li>";
 resultado += "</ul>";

 document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = resultado;

}

videos("2");
```

```html
<div id="contenido"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias y ahora si comprendo como funciona, de hecho la solucion anterior si me es mas efectivo ya que en mi caso tengo como 60 videos de los cuales 3 son de la seccion 1 los otros 5 son de la seccion 2 y asi varia la cantidad y la seccion de origen del video. Pero tu sugerencia la marque como valida porque en efecto como la explicas funcionaria de forma automatica con la posicion del array

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a seguir buscando por numeros podes usar el index. Simplemente lo restas con uno y listo. `VIDEOS[busqueda-1]`

Ejecuta y fijate en el ejemplo. En los comentarios del codigo hay mas explicacion.

```js
const VIDEOS = [
  {
    nombre: "Video 1",
    ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
    archivo: "presentacion.mp4",
    seccion: 1
  },
  {
    nombre: "Video 2",
    ruta: "media/videos/Bienvenida/",
    archivo: "origenes.mp4",
    seccion: 2
  }
]
function getDivContenido(){
  return document.getElementById('contenido')
}

function addTitle(title){
    let h1Element = document.createElement('h1')
  h1Element.classList.add("title")
    getDivContenido().appendChild(h1Element).innerText = title
}

function createUlTag(){
    let ulTag = document.createElement('ul')
  ulTag.setAttribute("id", "ul-list");
  getDivContenido().appendChild(ulTag)
}
function getUlElement(){
    return document.getElementById('ul-list')
}
function createLiTag(){
    let liTag = document.createElement('li')
  return liTag
}

function getVideo(busqueda){
    //controlamos que el valor de busqueda este entre el rango del lenght deL array VIDEOS.
    if ((busqueda-1) >= VIDEOS.length || busqueda <= 0 ) {
      window.alert("No hay video con ese indice")
    }else{
      //Aqui en vez de utilizar alguna funcion para iterar por el array simplemente utilizo el index
      //nosotros los informaticos sabemos que en progamacion se empeza a contar de 0
      //entonces lo que hago es agarrar numero del video que queres buscar y lo resto con 1
      // ejemplo queres el video 2
      //busqueda = 2
      //VIDEOS[busqueda-1] agarra el objeto que esta en la posicion 1.

      // esta linea esta destructurando el objeto y lo asigna a las respectivas variables
      //las variables serian archivoVideo, nombreVideos y asi sucesivamente.
      let {archivo: archivoVideo, nombre: nombreVideo, ruta: rutaVideo, seccion: seccionVideo} = VIDEOS[busqueda-1]

      let liArchivo = createLiTag()
      liArchivo.innerText = archivoVideo
      getUlElement().appendChild(liArchivo)

      let liNombre = createLiTag()
      liNombre.innerText = nombreVideo
      getUlElement().appendChild(liNombre)

      let liRuta = createLiTag()
      liRuta.innerText = rutaVideo
      getUlElement().appendChild(liRuta)  

      let liSeccion = createLiTag()
      liSeccion.innerText = seccionVideo
      getUlElement().appendChild(liSeccion)  
    }  
}

//invocamos las funciones
addTitle('Lista de Videos')
createUlTag()
getVideo(2)
getVideo(1)
getVideo(0)
getVideo(-4)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container" id="contenido"></div>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Saludos!